# How to add each and every value of sharedpref.getstringset to an arraylist?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, setstring

I'm trying to put user names in string set by using `SharedPreferences.putstringset`, the problem is that I want to get each  name(value) the user put and add it to an arraylist and print each value.

I tried `pref.getstringset` but I don't know how to do it.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor=pref.edit();
editor.putStringSet("user names",usernames.getText().toString());
editor.commit();
```

Comment: You can use getStringSet to get the HashSet back and then iterate overit.

Comment: I tried pref.getstringset but I don't know how to do it, as mentioned in the question above.

Comment: You can use `Gson` try this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/53606612/10037223](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53606612/10037223)

Answer (score 1):

Store the user names in a set like this :-

```
Set<String> userNames = new HashSet<>();
userNames.add(usernames.getText().toString())
```

Then `put` the set in share preferences :-

```
editor.putStringSet("user names",userNames);
editor.commit();
```

Then finally get it with a `default value` and `print` it :-

```
for(String name : pref.getStringSet("user names", new HashSet<>()))
    System.out.println(name);
```

Comment: an error message say(ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Set at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getStringSet(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:234)).. The compiler was refering to this line of code
( for(String name : pref.getStringSet("user names", new HashSet<>())) System.out.println(name);)

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<String> fetch = editor.getStringSet("your_key", null);
Iterator value = set.iterator(); 
while (value.hasNext()) { 
   //do whatever you want
   //add to the arraylist

}
```